# How to read large data set at hourly interval

Tags: elasticsearch, workflow, bigdata, apache-kafka

For example, I have 30million records, stored in our datastore. Then I want to read a fraction  of them randomly at 2 hours interval: e.g I want to read 1 million random records every 2 hours, and do something about them. What would be the best approach to solve this kind of problem?

1. Should I read 30million all out, and store them in  a
   queue(e.g,Kafak), then have a job running every 2 hours to read from
   the queue.
2. Or should I just design my query to read 1 million
       records,then have a job, every 2hours run the query, get the
       dataset, and then delete them after processing?

Is there any open source framework that is suitable for this situation? How can I schedule the job only when I have the total data in place?

Thanks,
Chen

Comment: With 30 million records, this should be doable yourself by sending a query that uses a seeded `random_score` that you can page out yourself using whatever Elasticsearch API (e.g., Java, Python, C#, etc).

Comment: I am aware that i can read them out by paging(scrolling) in ES. The question is more about the system design about the workflow: where should I store the query result, how to schedule the workflow etc.